# Unable to set text to a textview in another activity

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to set a text to a textview in another activity, but im getting an error while the app is running :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the main activity :-

```
package com.example.testlab;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RocketDetailsActivity rda;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        rda = new RocketDetailsActivity();
        button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            callRocketDetails();
            setDetails("Custom Starship", "SFS Gaming",
                    "22-05-2020", "NIL", R.drawable.rocket1);
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            callRocketDetails();
            setDetails("Eagle 1+", "SFS Gaming",
                    "22-05-2020", "NIL", R.drawable.rocket2);
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            callRocketDetails();
            setDetails("Space Station", "SFS Gaming",
                    "22-05-2020", "NIL", R.drawable.rocket3);
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            callRocketDetails();
            setDetails("Eagle 9+ 1st Stage", "SFS Gaming",
                    "22-05-2020", "NIL", R.drawable.rocket4);
        });
    }
    public void callRocketDetails() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RocketDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    public void setDetails(String rocketNameS, String rocketBuilderS, String rocketDateS,
                           String rocketDescS, int rocketImageS) {
        RocketDetailsActivity rda = new RocketDetailsActivity();
        rda.rocketName.setText(rocketNameS);
        rda.rocketBuilder.setText(rocketBuilderS);
        rda.rocketDate.setText(rocketDateS);
        rda.rocketDesc.setText(rocketDescS);
        rda.rocketImg.setImageResource(rocketImageS);
    }
}
```

at this point, im getting error:-

```
        (here)rda.rocketBuilder.setText(rocketBuilderS);
        rda.rocketDate.setText(rocketDateS);
        rda.rocketDesc.setText(rocketDescS);
        rda.rocketImg.setImageResource(rocketImageS);
```

And here is the rocket details activity:-

```
package com.example.testlab;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RocketDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView rocketName;
    TextView rocketBuilder;
    TextView rocketDate;
    TextView rocketDesc;
    ImageView rocketImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rocket_details);
        rocketName = findViewById(R.id.textRocketName);
        rocketBuilder = findViewById(R.id.textRocketBuilder);
        rocketDate = findViewById(R.id.textRocketDate);
        rocketDesc = findViewById(R.id.textRocketDesc);
        rocketImg = findViewById(R.id.rocketImage);
        Button downloadBP = findViewById(R.id.buttonDownloadBP);
        Button back = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        Button exit = findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
        back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
    }
}
```

I know there are answers for NullPointerException out there, but I want the solution for this specific code. Please help me point it out. Thanks.

Comment: You are setting text value in MainActivity but that TextView belongs to RocketDetailsActivity. You cannot reference views in activity which does not belongs to it's layout.

Comment: @Rajasekhar i have different approach to this problem, please see it.

Comment: Yout logic is the problem here, you want to show values on another activity that are set on the first activity, the way that you are doing is wrong, [Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) is the way to go

Comment: Yes I fixed it by passing values through adding them to intent

Comment: Problem fixed..